# Can I import symbology from an .axl file into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-server, symbology, arcims

I'm setting up new Arcserver services, and some users would like the symbology in the new services to match the old IMS services.  With that in mind, is it possible to either:

a) import the symbology from an axl file into ArcMap
b) convert the axl file to an avl file so the symbology can be imported

Thanks in advance for any help, any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [ArcScript](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14007)